# Same coordinate system between two objects C#

Tags: c#, robotics, coordinate-systems, kinect-sdk

I am writing a code using C#. I use a Kinect SDK V2 and a robot, for example my robot model is an IRB 1600. From the Kinect sensor I take a human point cloud when a human is detecting from the camera and from the robot I take one position (X-Y-Z position) that tells me where the robot is every time I ask it.

My problem is that the camera and robot have got different coordinate systems the sensor have the sender of the camera and the robot has his bases. I want to create a same coordinate system between them for distance calculation between human and robot. Are any methods to do that? tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make a calibration...

Somewhere you need to say that your 3D coordinate system starts at (0,0,0) and then re-convert all the positions based on this coordinate system. Shouldn't be hard to implement.

Nevertheless, if you have both 3D positions of the two sensors, a simple calculation in 3D gives you the distance.

Distance=sqrt(X2-X1)^2+(Y2-Y1)^2+(Z2-Z1)^2)